# Two shell scripts using same variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have two shell scripts test1.sh and test2.sh.
In test1.sh I have the below statements :
In, **test1.sh**,I have a variable **I** whose value will be used by **test2.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
I="10"
echo $I
```

In, **test2.sh**, the same value of the variable will be copied and printed

```
#!/bin/sh
J=$I
echo $J
```

I need to run both the scripts in crontab, I tried **export** command, but nothing worked.

Comment: Are the two scripts running separately, or are you calling one from the other? In which order are the scripts called?

Comment: They are two different scripts, firstly test1.sh is called and then the test2.sh is called.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to you crontab :

```
. ./test1.sh && ./test2.sh;
```

And modify you test1.sh like that :

```
#!/bin/sh
export I="10"
echo $I
```

With `.` the first will be executed as source and will hold variables.

Answer (score 1):

Both scripts are running in their own shell, and only share their environment with their *parent* process. If you want two separate shell scripts to share environment variables, the variables have to be set (and exported) in the parent process before calling the scripts.

You could also create a third script that only sets the variables, and source that script from the two main scripts.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the output of `test1.sh` in script `test2.sh`, you have two options

- store the output of `test1.sh` in a file and read that file back in `test2.sh`
- call `test1.sh` from `test2.sh`

test2.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
J=$(test1.sh)
echo $J
```

As @Joachim Pileborg already suggested, you can set (but not echo) variables in one script and source it in the other one

test1.sh

```
I="10"
J=20
K=30
```

test2.sh

```
source test1.sh
# do something with I, J, K
```

Comment: If I have more than one variable, how should I write the code.

Comment: @Vishu Joachim Pileborg already suggested sourcing the script.